# How can I use the J2EE container to manage my user authentication?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, containers

I have a J2EE web application inside of Tomcat that I am writing.

For user login, I have stored salted password hashes inside of MySQL. To login, a user provides a password, it is hashed and compared to the database password. This seems OK to me, but I have heard that the container (Tomcat) provides some user authentication services.

I have looked into it a little bit, but all I can find is how to add user accounts by hand to the system. However, I would like for users to register and the container to handle the dynamic changes.

Is there a way to dynamically modify the user account list to allow people to register on the fly using the J2EE container?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat you may be interested on the [JDBCRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) of which, there may be custom implementations floating around if you want to extend it. Although Tomcat is not a full blown J2EE container, you may want to read an overview of [Defining Security Requirements for Web Applications](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html) for a more standard approach that works on any J2EE container.

Comment: What if I was using Glassfish? Would that be much different?

Comment: For authentication purposes, all of the above apply to Glassfish. Probably you'll find jdbcrealm tutorials in google.